# How to import without using "import" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, subprocess, python-2.x

The context of this question is that I am trying to write a program for assist in analysis of data. It should be written in python3, however the kind of data it is for is usually stored in a format that python cannot read.
There is a package to the read these data but it is only compatible with python2. In order to the read the data I therefore wanted to write a python2 scripts that reads the file and converts it into a numpy array. This I want to read in my python3 program. (The package in question is axographio[1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/axographio)).

In generality what I want is this:

Given a (python2) script like

```
#reading.py
import numpy
x = numpy.random.random(size=10000)
```

run a (python3) that can somehow get x

```
#analyze.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#fancyfunction that gets x from reading.py
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

It is important here that reading.py be executed by the python2 interpreter since it will not work with python3.

Comment: why not doing everything in python 2.7 ? An other option is having a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args. And as third option is to do it in two time : 1- in python2 read your data and write a new file (.txt, .dat, etc...), 2-read this file in python3 script, 3-write a small shell script that will call both to make it more easy for the user.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to pickle the data

In python 2

```
import pickle
pickle.dumps(x)
```

In python 3

```
import pickle
pickle.load(x)
```

If I remember correctly, a better approach is to save your numpy array in a json file (maybe using panda over numpy) in python 2, and do the reverse in python 3

Something like that :

```
df = pandas.Data[...]
```

See [http://www.thegeeklegacy.com/t/how-to-import-without-using-import-in-python/35/#post-103](http://www.thegeeklegacy.com/t/how-to-import-without-using-import-in-python/35/?utm_source=stackoverflow) for the details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about storing the data in a file but wanted to avoid if possible.

Comment: Anyway, I will accept your answer if you update it  a little so that it could be run. (pickle.dumps take more than one argument afaik)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I used.
From the `subprocess` module I used the function `Popen` with argument `shell=True` to call my python2 scripts from the python3 and collected the `stdout`. (This means everything has be printed to the console.)

This is python2 code I want to call in python3:

```
#readying.py
import axographio #this is the python2 package
import os #specific to the problem of reading data
import sys #needed to use arguments from the command line
if __name__=='__main__': #when y
    path = sys.argv[1]
    filename = sys.argv[2]
    os.chdir(path)
    file = axographio.read(filename)
    # print 'done reading files'

    data = file.data

    no_measurements = len(data)
    measurement_len = len(data[0])

    print(no_measurements)
    print(measurement_len)
    for i, name in enumerate(file.names):
        print(name)
    for i in range(no_measurements):
        for j in range(measurement_len):
            print(data[i][j])
        print('next measurement') 
       #this acts as a seperator when reading the data in python3, anything that cannot be converted to a float works
```

What this code does is simply take argument from the commad line. (Using the `sys` module they can be passed to a .py scripts in the command line in the form `python2 script.py arg1 arg2 arg2`. 
The output of `reading.py` is given out using print statements. Note that I print every datum individually in order to avoid truncation of the output. In this way the output is the standard output `stdout` of the `python2` call.

The python3 code is

```
#analyze.py
import subprocess
import numpy as np

def read_data(path, filename):
    module_name = 'reading.py'
    cmd = 'python2 '+module_name+' '+path+' '+filename
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    #out is a bytes object

    result = out.split(b'\n') #the output from different print statements is seperated by "b'\n'" in the bytes object


    #everything below here is concerned with unpacking the output and structuring it as I needed it         
    output = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(result):
        output.append(result[i].decode("utf-8"))
        i+=1
    ind = 0 #this should keep track of where in the output list we are
    no_measurements = int(output[ind])
    ind += 1
    measurement_len = int(output[ind])
    ind += 1

    names = []
    for i in np.arange(ind,ind+no_measurements):
        names.append(output[i])
        ind += 1

    data = []
    measurement = []
    while ind<len(output):
        try:
            measurement.append(float(output[ind]))
            ind+=1
        except:
            data.append(measurement)
            measurement = []
            ind+=1
    data = np.array(data)

    return names, data
```

What this does is to use the `subprocess` module to execute as a shell command `python2 reading.py path filename`. As mentioned above the `stdout` of this call is the output of its `print` statements. These are `bytes` objects encoded with 'UTF-8'. Using the `decode` method they can be converted to string objects which can then be changed in type using functions like `float`. (This is another reason why it is useful to print everything seperately since it is rather annoying to have to scan through a string to find arrays or numbers.) In `readying.py` data are seperated explicitely while being printed which makes it easy to structure them once they are read.

Tags: axographio in python3--read axograph files python3