# is it possible import variable from file to another and process then return the result to the first

Tags: python, optimization, data-oriented-design

## First.py

```
x = 5
b = 6
from second import c
def print_():
   result = c
   print (ersult)
print_()
```

## second.py

```
from First import x,b
class addition():
   def process(self):
       c = x + b
       return c
```

> the variables in the first file (first)
>
> the second file obtain the variables then do the function
>
> then the  first file obtain the result from second file and do the
> function

I wonder is it possible!!!
or the right choice is the variable be separated in third file, or if the code isn't long, combine all in the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work correctly because you have a circular import. `First.py` imports from `second.py` and visa versa. Rather than trying to import `First.py` into second, have `addition.process` take the necessary parameters to do your computation, import `addition` into `First.py`, and call `addition.process` their:

### second.py

```
class addition():
   def process(self, x, b):
       c = x + b
       return c
```

### First.py

```
x = 5
b = 6
from second import addition
def print_():
   result = addition().process(x, b)
   print (result)
print_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides Christian Dean's answer you could have a look here: [run a python script from another python script passing in args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-arguments).