# How to import the main function from a Python file not defining "def main" in it?

Tags: python, python-import, program-entry-point

I am writing a Python (3.5) module in which I'd like to make use of an existing Python module from an open source project. The module I want to import contains:

- several functions
- a `if __name__ ==  '__main__':` instruction

but does not contain a `def main(args)` function.

Because there is no actual `main` function, I cannot import it by means of `import module` and use it as `module.main()`. Although I did find options to separately execute it as script via the commands `os.system()` and `subprocess.Popen()`, I am actually looking for a way to make this call an integral part of my code.

I understand I can add the `def main()` part myself in the original code, but because it comes from an open source project, I am looking for ways to leave it untouched, so that I don't need to maintain it myself if it gets updated.

I have gone through other very similar questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files/20749411#20749411) that could not solve my issue. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3783185/1844776) gives me the feeling what I am trying to do is not trivial.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In theory, you could write some sort of nasty import hook that rewrites the ast to turn `if __name__ == '__main__'` into a function. In practice, this is probably a recipe for really weird bugs and maintenance nightmares. Have you considered just submitting a pull request to add a `main` function?

Comment: If the module is written that way, it's entirely possible that the author considers the code inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to be module initialization code that must not be run more than once.

Comment: @LarryLustig, that might be actually true. I was hoping to find a large shortcut and pick-up existing code as much as possible, but if I think it that way, I might not be doing the right thing if I called _that_ script/function all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `import` a module for the first time, (as distinguished from importing a function), all code in that module executes.  That means functions become defined, global variables become defined, etc. The reason we write an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block is so that when importing a module, that code does not execute (it will only execute [if **name** == "**main**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).  If you simply remove the `if __name__ == "__main__":` line and fix the indentation, that code will execute when you import the module.  take this module `hello.py` for example:

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello world")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()
```

then if we import:

```
import hello
hello_world()
```

The code below will do the same thing as this case where the first module is again hello.py:

```
def hello_world():
    print("hello world")
hello_world()
```

module to be executed:

```
import hello
```

I recommend you do not do it this way though, you really should just edit to include a main function.

Comment: First, it won't execute every time you import the module; it'll only execute the first time (per Python process). Second, the questioner does not want to edit the file. Third, even for solutions that involve editing the file, adding a `main` function is a better way.

Comment: I've corrected my answer re your first point, I didn't notice your second point, and I always agreed with, but have edited to explicate your third.