# Running two scripts at the same time from parental script

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new in python and I want to start running script2.py and script3.py when I manually run script1.py. For now I'm only capable to run one script from script1.py, but when I want the two scripts running from script1.py it fails.

Important is that script2.py and script3.py both immediately start running when I run script1.py

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: This looks like a XY problem, why do you want these scripts to run "at the same time" ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate:
[Run a python script from another python script, passing in args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args)

Try using [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) at the beginning of your file:

```
os.system("script2.py")
os.system("script3.py")
```