# How to call another Python 3 script and pass it some arguments

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. The file "main.py" must call the file "add.py". I want to invoke the interpreter as

```
python main.py add John Doe Some Possible Names
```

That is variable length for sys.argv. I want from within main.py to call for add.py and pass it all the arguments except add and main.py. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you pass in `add` rather than `add.py`, but nevertheless, you can use `subprocess.call`:

```
import sys, subprocess
subprocess.call([sys.executable, sys.argv[1] + '.py'] + sys.argv[2:])
```

Comment: add is just an ordinary argument. add.py is the second script. main.py is the main script.

Comment: I know, but why not pass in `add.py` as the argument since that is the script you want to call... Anyway, does this work for you?

Comment: note: it's better to use `sys.executable` instead of `python` because it allows to reuse the same interpreter (some interpreters aren't in the path, or aren't called python)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Makes sense! Thanks for the tip.