# simple call from one python script to another passing a simple parameter

Tags: python, linux, parameters

Here are two scripts.
First one called first_py:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python  
    import sys   

    print sys.argv[0] # prints python_script.py    
    print sys.argv[1] # prints var1
    print "first one"
```

Here's the second one called sec_py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print sys.argv[0] # prints sec_script.py
print sys.argv[1] # prints var1

print "second one"

x=5
myVars = {'x':x}
exec(open('first_py').read(), myVars)
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass the number '5' as a parameter from the second script to the first script while calling it. It's not working.

How can I fix the second script so it calls first_py and passes the value of 'x' to it so the value 5 is printed out?

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate the actual functionality into a function, and then just import and call it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a python script from another python script, passing in args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import subprocess, shlex
print sys.argv[0] # prints sec_script.py
print sys.argv[1] # prints var1

print "second one"

x=5
myVars = {'x':x}
print subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('first_py {0}'.format(myVars['x'])))
```

There are many ways to do what you're trying to do - we should note particularly putting the print statement in a function (say, `print_value()`) in `first_py`, *importing* `first_py`, and then using `first_py.print_value(myVars['x'])`. I think, however, that the subprocess solution is the closest one to the one you have already drafted.

PS - I would save my scripts as, e.g., `first.py`, rather than `first_py`.

Comment: Tried it and got the following error: $ ./sec_py.py TOM
./sec_py.py
TOM
second one
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sec_py.py", line 15, in <module>
    print subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('first_py {0}'.format(myVars['x'])))
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Comment: I think you probably forgot `import subprocess, shlex` at the top (line #4)

Comment: But - seriously - use `import first_py; first_py.print_value(...)` way of doing it - it's a lot cleaner and better

Comment: Should I be including a path name to first_py because  it's not recognizing the file. I'm getting. $ ./sec_py.py TOM
  File "./sec_py.py", line 4
    import first_py,first_py.print_value(myVars['x'])
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Split `import first_py` and `first_py.print_value(...)` into separate lines!