# How to execute python scrapy from outside of the scrape folder

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to be able to run python scrapy from the `app.py` file, without `cd ..` into the scrape folder to run the application.

This is how my current directory looks like

[image]

This is what i have to do to execute the scrapy app

[image]

I want to be able to run the app just doing python app.py, and possibly do this without being in virutalenv.

My `app.py` is blank, cause im unsure how to tell python how to run the app, from the app file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

**App.py**

```
import os
import subprocess 

cw = os.getcwd()
path = '/scrape'
ourPath = cw + os.path.join(path)

if(ourPath):
    os.chdir(ourPath)
    os.system('scrapy crawl yellow')
```

Comment: You are importing `subprocess` but not using it. You should learn how to specify the working directory with `subprocess` and update your response accordingly.