# import and call new file modules from a for loop

Tags: python

I have a file directory like so..

myScript.py

--Projects

----Test

------test0.py

------test1.py

------test2.py

From myScript.py I am trying to use a for loop to iterate over the files in the project directory and run the main module of each.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


def main(project_loc="Test"):
    print('I am main of main')
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    project_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'Projects', project_loc)
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(project_dir) if isfile(join(project_dir, f))]
    count = 0 
    for file in onlyfiles:
        file_name = os.path.join(project_dir, file).rstrip('.py')
        print('File' + str(count), file_name)
        new_module = __import__(file_name)
        #new_module.main()                 #Run module I just imported
        count += 1
    print(modules)

    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

myScript.py above

```
def main():
    print('I am main of file 0')
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

test0.py above(rest are similar)

It is not an option to just import those three files because there is more then just them.

It is also **not** an option to use an additional libraries.
It must be done using only modules already packaged with python

Comment: So you want to get all the .py files from the CWD and execute them on the fly?

Comment: Just as a note, [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) is part of the python standard library (therefore, it comes packaged with python)

Comment: @araraonline Oh, I had no clue I must have imported it wrong! I'll remove that part from the post

Comment: @VigneshSP Not quite, I was to get all the files from two directories down and execute a module in those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `__import__` is being called with the path to the files as a parameter (eg `~/directory/Projects/Test/test0`). Instead `__import__` takes a `name` parameter that should look something like `Projects.Test.test0`.

Now, to run the scripts you want, there are various options. Please see [Run a Python script from another Python script, passing in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-arguments)

Comment: I've made this community wiki because I don't think this is a quality answer. The actual substance is in the question linked.