# Python os.system run in 64bit mode

Tags: python, 64-bit, os.system

I have a python script (lets call it a.py) that imports several packages (i.e. arcpy) which have to be used in 64bit-mode.

Then I want to call a.py from b.py with `os.system("a.py")`

However, this throws an error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

When I run a.py directly, it runs smoothly. So I suggest, `os.system()` does not use 64-bit-mode.
Is there a way to force `os.system()` to run in 64-bit mode? Or is there another way to call a script from another script and choose the mode in which it is called?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using something like `os.system("python a.py")`?

Comment: Do you have multiple python installs? Are you using a virtual environment? Your script a.py might not be running with the same python you are running the script b.py from. Also, consider using subprocess https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess over os.system.

Comment: @jmd_d4 indeed, this helps :-) I was using the code from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-arguments which does not state "python" first....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a Python script from another Python script, passing in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-arguments)

Comment: @Mario That won't work on Windows because the Windows shell doesn't know how to execute a Python script.  On UNIX-like systems this is possible with the use of a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), but this does not have an equivalent on Windows.  If I were you I would also make sure you really need to run a script as a separate process instead of just importing one module from another and building a pipeline Pythonically.

Comment: @Iguananaut – More or less: It needs os.system("*python* a.py")

Comment: Also this has nothing to do with 64-bit anything; on Windows all applications are referred to as "Win32" applications whether or not it's a 64-bit OS.  All it's trying to tell you is that a Python script is not an executable from Windows' perspective.