# How do I pass any file path as a command line argument from one program to another program in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am trying to develop a code between two python program where I pass a command line argument for the second program to execute from the first program.

Comment: How are you invoking the second program from the first?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to call a function from the second program instead of using command-line arguments. You can do this by importing the said function.

Another approach would be to use command-line arguments as you said, with the command **System** or the **Subprocess** module.

Answer (score 0):

> main.py

```
import os
os.system('python3 test.py 1 2 3')
```

Other program's main file

> test.py

```
import sys

print('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
print('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
```

> Output

```
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['test.py', '1', '2', '3']
```

Run main.py which runs test.py file with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your first_program.py :

```
import os
os.system('python3.6 /path/to/second_program.py arg1')
```

These look related :

[Run a Python script from another Python script, passing in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-arguments)

[How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

[What is the best way to call a script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script)