# Looping through variables in file 1 and executing it in file 2

Tags: python, loops

Background:

I'm creating a report that gets sent out to various users in the organization.

I have 3 separate files to do this.

The solution works fine, however it just keeps producing the same file over and over again for the last user in the list.The variable that is being saved is only the last one being executed. It should be producing a different file for each user. I'm not sure if this a nested loop issue, but see below for more context:

---

File 1) **subscribers.py** - a list of emails:

```
subscriber_list = ['abe@gmail.com','obama@gmail.com','clinton@gmail.com']
```

File 2) **start.py** - loops through subscribers to execute third file:

```
import subscribers


for user in subscribers.subscriber_list :
    login_input = user
    exec(open('produce_report.py').read())
```

File 3) **produce_report.py** - runs through a series of logic based on login_input, for simplicity I'm just going to print the value.

```
import subscribers 
import start


login_input = start.login_input

print (start.login_input)
```

**Expected Result:**

- abe@gmail.com
- obama@gmail.com
- clinton@gmail.com

**Result I'm getting:**

- clinton@gmail.com
- clinton@gmail.com
- clinton@gmail.com

Comment: In `start.py` `login_input` gets updated every iteration of the for loop, preserving only the last updated value.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a function in `produce_report` so you can pass info from `start` to the function - making the imports in `produce_report` unnecesary?

Comment: Or have `produce_report` rely on command line parameters/arguments and execute it from `start`?

Comment: How are you executing this solution? If I create a fourth .py file with `import start` in it, it seems to work and produce the expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a Python script from another Python script, passing in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-arguments)

Comment: Instead of `import start`, try `import __main__` and then `__main__.login_input`

Comment: @Luke-zhang-04 so that worked... how do I add a fourth file...and carry the variable from the third to the fourth? The `__main__` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of import start, try `import __main__` and then `__main__.login_input`

`import __main__` just imports the executable script, so the fourth file with `import __main__` will just import `start.py` again. Your best bet is to write a function in the fourth file and pass in parameters. To do this you would import your function in `produce_report`.
There's also another option. Since you are saving the variable in `start.py`, why don't you carry the variable from `start.py` to the fourth file?