# Running python script inside ipython

Tags: python, path, ipython

Is it possible to run a python script (not module) from inside ipython without indicating its path? I tried to set PYTHONPATH but it seems to work only for modules. 
I would like to execute

```
%run my_script.py
```

without being in the directory containing the file.

Comment: `import <module>` is essentially the same as `exec(<moduleSource>)` in JavaScript or Perl.

Comment: +1 for the syntax %run abc.py -- was trying to look for that

Comment: you can use the path: %run ../scripts/my_scripts for example

Comment: for CLI scripts developed with the Click library it doesn't work to me, I get: 

IOErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
/home/miguelfg/workspace/projects*********/db_preparation.py in <module>()
   1270 
   1271 if __name__ == "__main__":
-> 1272     main()
   1273 
   1274 
...

Answer (score 170):

from within the directory of "my_script.py" you can simply do:

```
%run ./my_script.py
```

Comment: best answer for simplicity and conciseness

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` here, on *Python console*. Python 3.5.3 on Debian 9.
However, works on IPython.

Comment: @rotton that's because `%run` is an ipython magic command, not part of the Python language itself.

Answer (score 32):

#### How to run a script in Ipython

```
import os
filepath='C:\\Users\\User\\FolderWithPythonScript' 
os.chdir(filepath)
%run pyFileInThatFilePath.py
```

That should do it

Answer (score 16):

In python there is no difference between modules and scripts; You can execute both scripts and modules.  The file must be on the pythonpath AFAIK because python must be able to find the file in question.  If python is executed from a directory, then the directory is automatically added to the pythonpath.

Refer to [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script) for more information about modules vs scripts

There is also a builtin function execfile(filename) that will do what you want

Comment: That is also what I thought. However, in practice modules can be imported but scripts are not found by the interpreter unless started from the directory they belong to.

Comment: Read http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path for more info.  It details where it must be put for python to find the file,  More specifically, many modules can double as scripts using the "if `__name__` == '`__main__`':" line at the end

Answer (score 16):

The `%run` magic has a parameter `file_finder` that it uses to get the full path to the file to execute (see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L322)); as you note, it just looks in the current directory, appending ".py" if necessary.

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify which file finder to use *from* the `%run` magic, but there's nothing to stop you from defining your own magic command that calls into `%run` with an appropriate file finder.

As a *very* nasty hack, you could override the default `file_finder` with your own:

```
IPython.core.magics.execution.ExecutionMagics.run.im_func.func_defaults[2] = my_file_finder
```

To be honest, at the rate the IPython API is changing that's as likely to continue to work as defining your own magic is.

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but you can drop into ipython at the end of a script's execution by using the `-i` parameter to ipython:

```
ipython -i my_script.py
```

At the end of the script you're dropped into the ipython prompt with the script's variables available to you, just like `python -i`.

Answer (score -3):

for Python 3.6.5

```
import os
os.getcwd()
runfile('testing.py')
```

Comment: Is `runfile()` a command of `ipython` ? Doesn't work out-of-box for me.

Comment: runfile seems to be specific to the pycharm console.