# how to run python script from the console as if called from command prompt?

Tags: python, cmd, console, ipython, spyder

The python script I would use (source code [here](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~hannes/importer.py)) would parse some arguments when called from the command line. However, I have no access to the Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) in my environment. Can I call the same script from within a Python console? I would rather not rewrite the script itself.

Comment: try to install python on your windows PC and add it at your environment....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744181/running-python-script-inside-ipython if you are using iPython as your console.

Comment: @Wolf Simply '%run' does the trick, thanks! Are there any pitfalls to that? Otherwise feel free to write up a a quick answer about it, I am happy to give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%run` is a magic in IPython that runs a named file inside IPython as a program almost exactly like running that file from the shell.  Quoting from `%run?` referring to `%run file args`:

This is similar to running at a system prompt `python file args`,
but with the advantage of giving you IPython's tracebacks, and of
loading all variables into your interactive namespace for further use
(unless -p is used, see below). (end quote)

The only downside is that the file to be run must be in the current working directory or somewhere along the `PYTHONPATH`.  `%run` won't search `$PATH`.

`%run` takes several options which you can learn about from `%run?`.  For instance: `-p` to run under the profiler.

Answer (score 0):

You want to spawn a new subprocess.

There's a module for that: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

**Examples:**

*Basic:*

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen


p = Popen(sys.executable, "C:\test.py")
```

*Getting the subprocess's output:*

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


p = Popen(sys.executable, "C:\test.py", stdout=PIPE)
stdout = p.stdout
print stdout.read()
```

See the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) API Documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make system calls, you can use:

```
import os
os.system("importer.py arguments_go_here")
```