# How can I see the search path for the Ipython console's %run command? How I can I add directories to it?

Tags: python, path, ipython

I have JModelica.org-2.0 which comes with its python installation. When I go to the Ipython console, type run and then press tab, I notice that it shows the scripts in the folder "C:\Users\Public\Documents\JModelica.org". How can I make it so that Ipython searches for scripts in other folders. I tried adding the folder to the PATH as well as PYTHONPATH variables but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running python script inside ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744181/running-python-script-inside-ipython)