# Equivalent of Spyder's runfile for IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

How can I get something like Spyder's `runfile` function in IPython?  (I'm using IPython v. 4.1.2 under Python 2.7.9.)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`%run`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744181/running-python-script-inside-ipython)?

Comment: @cmaher: that works for me; thanks!  Care to post your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python files can be executed within the IPython environment using the magic command [`%run`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run).

Example:

```
print_time.py
# #!/usr/bin/python
# 
# from datetime import datetime
# 
# print "The current time is {}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

In [1]: %run print_time.py
The current time is 21:37:46
```

More information on how to run files outside your working directory can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744181/running-python-script-inside-ipython).

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, `runfile` is also included as a builtin function in PyCharm, another IDE. PyCharm's Python Console use IPython by default if you have it installed, and `runfile` works there. Just another option.