# python - using functions from a different py script gives NameError

Tags: python, function

I have a py script, lets call it MergeData.py, where I merge two data files. Since I have a lot of pairs of data files that have to be merged I thought it would be good for readability reasons to put my code in MergeData.py into a function, say merge_data(), and call this function in a loop over all my pairs of data files in a different py script.

2 Questions:

1. Is it wise, in terms of speed, to call the function from a different file instead of runing the code directly in the loop? (I have thousands of pairs that have to be merged.)
2. I thought, to use the function in MergeData.py I have to include in the head of my script from MergedData import merge_data. Within the function merge_data I make use of pandas which I import in the main file by 'import pandas as pd'. When calling the function I get the error 'NameError: global name 'pd' is not defined'. I have tried all possible places to import the pandas modul, even within the function, but the error keeps popping up. What am I doing wrong?

In MergeData.py I have

```
def merge_data(myFile1,myFile2):
       df1 = pd.read_csv(myFile1)
       df2 = pd.read_csv(myFile2)
       # ... my code
```

and in the other file I have

```
import pandas as pd
from MergeData import merge_data
# then some code to get my file names followed by
FileList = zip(FileList1,FileList2)

for myFile1,myFile2 in FileList:
    # Run Merging Algorithm
    dataEq = merge_data(myFile1,myFile2)
```

I am aware of [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script), but cannot really see if that relates to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the line

```
import pandas as pd
```

Into the module in which the symbol `pd` is actually needed, i.e. move it out of your "other file" and into your `MergeData.py` file.

Comment: That's weired. I am sure I tried this one, because it naturally presents itself a possible solution. Probably I forgot to save the modul after including pd. Any take on number 1?

Comment: Regarding number 1, it is perfectly fine to do that and there will be very little difference in performance