# Run a python script from another python script while the 2nd is paused

Tags: python

I have a pythons script that needs to run another script.

Flow from **python_script_1.py:**

```
run python_script_2.py
pause till python_script_2.py is done
continue python_script_1.py flow
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a python script from another python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

Comment: no - i need here to pause the calling script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).

For example:

You have `script_1.py` and `script_2.py` and you want to run the last from the first, so you can:

```
# script_1.py

import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python', 'script_2.py'],  # The command line.
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,   # The error output pipe.
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,   # The standar output pipe.
)

output, error = p.communicate() # This will block the execution(interpretation) of script_1 till 
                                # script_2 ends.
```

of course that is the solution if for some reason you can't import the code from `script_2.py` as the others answers shows.

Answer (score 0):

Normally what you want to do is something similar to this:

#### python_script_2.py

```
def func():
    print 'running python_script_2.func()'
```

#### python_script_1.py

```
import python_script_2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'before'
    python_script_2.func()
    print 'after'
```

*Output*

```
before
running python_script_2.func()
after
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to execute some code of the second Python script inside your main module. If you don't have any multithreading management in your code (so 'sequential execution'), you can just do:

#### script1.py

```
from script2 import my_process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Be prepared to call stuff from script2")
    my_process()
    print("Ok, now script2 has finished, we are back in script1")
```

#### script2.py

```
def my_process():
    # do Stuff
```