# Python command in python script from another python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I read already this [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

In my case I don't want to call another python script in a python script, but I want to call for example the ssylze.py with the specific options

```
$ python sslyze.py --regular www.target1.com
```

like consider in https://code.google.com/p/sslyze/wiki/QuickStart

So I have script test1.py and in that script I would like to use

```
sslyze.py --regular www.target1.com
```

how I do that?

Comment: subprocess.Popen(["python", "sslyze.py", "--regular", "www.target1.com"])

Comment: Why don't you just `import sslyze` and call whatever entry point function the command line call would? If it's sensibly structured, this will be trivial.

Comment: @paddyg the subprocess works fine, but I have two problems. for the "www.target1.com" I want to use a variable, so that I can make for-loop and read form txt different ips (but it didn't work out), and the second one is that I don't want that this command print the information on the console, but that it print this in a new file.

Comment: import subprocess


file_in = open("ip.txt", "r")
fname = "scan.txt" 
file_out = open("scan.txt","w")
i = 1
for line in file_in:
    print line
    process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "sslyze.py", "--regular", line], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print process.stdout.read()
    i = i + 1
file_out.close()
file_in.close()  the problem is that it only can scan the last ip, at the others ips it says "=> WARNING: Could not resolve hostname; discarding corresponding tasks."

Comment: @paddyg process.wait() was missing , that was my problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I've unscrambled the code from your comment ok and whether this is what you are trying to do. As I don't know what sslyze.py is doing I haven't tested it. However your problem might be due to not waiting for each subprocess to terminate:

```
import subprocess 
with open("ip.txt", "r") as file_in:
  fname = "scan.txt" 
  with open("scan.txt","w") as file_out:
    for line in file_in: 
      process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "sslyze.py", "--regular", line], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
      file_out.write(process.communicate()) # you might need to append \n to whatever you write
```

Comment: if I do it like that - I get the following exception: "File "SHA1Scanner.py", line 38, in <module>
    file_out.write(process.communicate())
TypeError: expected a character buffer object"

Comment: process.wait() was missing , that was my problem. but thanks for the indirect tip with the "with" command - it is much better that I did ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", "--regular", action="store")
args = parser.parse_args()
print vars(args)["regular"]
```

Running the above snippet (asd.py) with `python asd.py --regular www.target1.com` will print "www.target1.com". Hope this provides enough of an example to be helpful.

Comment: it is not my intention to print the domain or I understand you wrong.