# Call a python script within another python script causes problems with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

After trying the solution offered by this thread:
[What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

I came along with another problem dealing with arguments.

I have:

test1.py

```
def some_func():
    print 'in test 1, unproductive'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test1.py executed as script
    # do something
    some_func()
```

service.py (with dummy arguments)

```
import argparse
import test1

actions = ['start', 'remove']
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("action", help="Possible actions are: "
    "'{d[0]}|{d[1]}' ".format(d=actions))
parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", help="Debug mode", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

def service_func():
    print 'service func'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # service.py executed as script
    # do something
    service_func()
    test1.some_func()
```

This works:

```
python service.py start
service func
in test 1, unproductive
```

However, if I want to add arguments in test1.py as well:

test1.py

```
import argparse

######## new stuff  ##########
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", help="Debug mode", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
##############################

def some_func():
    print 'in test 1, unproductive'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test1.py executed as script
    # do something
    some_func()
```

Now I get:

```
python service.py start
usage: service.py [-h] [-d]
service.py: error: unrecognized arguments: start
```

Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

`python service.py start` - to `argparse` 'start' looks like a positional argument.  It does not have a '--' to mark it as a flag string.

I'm guessing the `parser` in `service.py` is handling it ok, though you don't display or otherwise use the resulting `args`.

The usage in the error message is consistent with the parser in `test1.py`.  It does not define a positional, just the `--debug`

```
usage: service.py [-h] [-d]
```

`test1.py` is using the same `sys.argv` list.

There are several solutions:

- add a positional argument to `test1`
- use `parse_known_args` instead of `parse_args`.
- modify `sys.argv` in `service.py` (after parsing) to remove this 'start' string.  A change in `sys.argv` in this script will carry over to `test1`.  Print `sys.argv` in both to be sure.
- use `REMAINDER` as documented in the docs

> argparse.REMAINDER. All the remaining command-line arguments are gathered into a list. This is commonly useful for command line utilities that dispatch to other command line utilities:

---

Call

```
args, extras = parser.parse_known_args()
```

This would set

`args` to `Namespace(debug=False)` and `extras` to `['start']`.  Otherwise you get a tuple of these two values, `(Namespace(debug=False), ['start'])`.

If you haven't modified `sys.argv` in the first script, the 2nd one will see the same list.  Parsing does not modify this list.

Comment: Oh, using `parse_known_args` instead of `parse_args` made it work. Thanks! I was trying the solution with REMAINDER but I'm not sure how/where to use it..

Comment: However, when printing the args variable for both scripts.. there is a problem:
test1.args:
  (Namespace(debug=False), ['start'])
services.args:
  Namespace(action='start', debug=False)

so the argument "start" is passed to test1.py somehow...