# Run one python script from another python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried every thing from

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

to

```
os.system()
```

I have looked through all the other similar questions on here and read official Python documentation.

I can't get this

```
import os

ask1 = raw_input("Create bid? ") 
create = "createbid.py %s" % ()
def questions():
    if ask1 == "yes":
        os.system(create)
    if ask1 == "no":
        quit()

question()
```

to run the ceatebid.py file reliably. I got it to work with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

but what if I also want to call another script?

I want to call different scripts based on how the questions are answered.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: have you try ***create = "python createbid.py %s" % ()*** instead of  ***create = "createbid.py %s" % ()***

Comment: I tried that. Both have the same results.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but in general you should be able to do something like this.

```
import foo
import bar

ask = raw_input("Do something?")
if ask.lower() in ('yes', 'y'):
    foo.do_something()
else:
    bar.do_other()
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to using `os.system("python createbid.py")` is to pass in a shell command in string format.

If you want to communicate with that script you probably want `subprocess`.
See the answer from this question: [running bash commands in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

This was probably answered here: [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

So, you need to define some method in you createbid.py (and other *scripts*):

```
def run()
    print 'running'
```

then in your main script,

```
import createbid

def questions():
    if ask1 == "yes":
        createbid.run()
    if ask1 == "no":
        quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    questions()
```

Comment: This worked when I used one other script. How do I choose from multiple other scripts?

Comment: You can import as many modules as you need, exactly how @batman suggests

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, the recommended way to launch other processes is to use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

It's relatively easy to do. Here's a simple way to apply it to your problem:

```
import subprocess
import sys

create = [sys.executable, 'createbid.py']

def question(ans):
    if ans == 'yes':
        subprocess.call(create)
    elif ans == 'no':
        quit()

ask1 = raw_input('Create bid? ')
question(ask1)
print('done')
```

**Note**: When `createbid.py` (or some other script) is executed this way,
`__name__ == '__main__'` *will* be `True`, unlike it would be if it had been `import`ed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `exec` (statement in Python2, function in Python3).

Suppose your script `scriptA` is stored in a file named `scriptA.py`. Then:

```
scriptContent = open("scriptA.py", 'r').read()
exec(scriptContent)
```

The merit of this is that `exec` allows you to define variables before, and use them inside of the script.

So if you were to define some parameters before running the script, you could still call them in your solution:

```
#Main script
param1 = 12
param2 = 23
scriptContent = open("scriptA.py", 'r').read()
exec(scriptContent)

#scriptA.py
print(param1 + param2)
```

Still, this approach is more like a fun trick, and depending on the situation, there should be several ways to do better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I combined a few answers to get it working.

This works:

```
import seebid
import createbid

ask1 = raw_input("Create bid? ")
ask2 = raw_input("View bid? ")
create = createbid
see = seebid

def questions():

    if ask1.lower() in ('yes', 'y'):
        create.createbd()
    elif ask1.lower() in ('no', 'n'):
        ask2

    if ask2.lower() in ('yes', 'y'):
        see.seebd()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    questions()
```