# Python - Importing a script as a module to run it entirely

Tags: python, import

I am trying to run python script from another python script. I know that I can go ahead and use os.system(), but it seems like importing the script of interest as a module is better practice. I understand that when imported, I can use the the different functions from the second script.

My question is what if I want to run the entire second script and not just a few functions from within it? How can I run the second script in its entirety at the end of my first script using the import way.

Thanks

Comment: `import foo` will execute all code within `./foo.py`. Its really not a good practice, but it will.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to build a main function where you put what the program is suppoused to do with the functions it has. for example let's say this is **your_module.py**

```
def some_function(arg):
    return print(arg)

def main():
    some_function('This is what the program')
    some_function('Is suppoused to do')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

if you import this from your **actual_file.py** it doesn't do anything, and you can use `some_function()` wherever you want, now, if you want to actually run what **actual_file.py** is suppoused to do, just call `main()`