# How to make sleep a file and use its function from another file in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, function, caching

I have have python file `a.py` which has a function `fun()`. `fun()` uses some libraries and global variables from `a.py`. The execution of `a.py` takes a lot of time but the execution of `fun()` is very fast once the libraries and global variables are ready. So I want to run `a.py` only once and use this variables and libraries every time I call the function `fun(`) from another file. For example I want to call `fun()` for every 2 seconds from another file. But I can't do this because `a.fun()` is taking more time to execute. I want to setup 'a.py' in such way that after importing libraries and executing `__main__` it sleeps or stops. After that whenever I am calling `a.fun()` from outside it should use the libraries already imported and the global variables calculated by `__main__`.  How to do this in python?

Comment: And the question is? ...

Comment: is there a way in python to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

Comment: This is different @cdarke

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `threading` module to run the function all 2 seconds regarless of how long the function takes

```
import a
import threading

while True:
    threading.Thread(target=a.fun).start()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Keep in mind that this program will only terminate if all Threads are dead.

Comment: That isn't the problem. If I do this all the libraries inside `a.py` will be imported again. This takes time. So the importing those libraries should take place only once. I want to call 'fun()'  for every 3 seconds from another file.

Comment: @prakash Now better?

Comment: No. :(
I want to edit a.py so that after one execution of `a.py`,`a.fun()` can be called everytime and whenever it calls `fun()` uses the libraries imported and global variables calculated during the first execution.