# How to return error line in a given file path for python?

Tags: python

I want `File1.py` to return the error line in `File2.py`

**File1.py:**

```
def find_errors(file_path_of_File2):
    print(f'the error is on line {}')
```

> the error is on line 2

**File2.py:**

```
print('this is line 1')
print(5/0)
```

> ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Is this possible?

Comment: Not possible: `ZeroDivisionError` is a runtime error, not a compile-time error. The only way to know it will be raised is to execute the code, and see it raised.

Comment: What's wrong if I executed File2.py through File1.py and saved the output of File2.py (which results in the error) and then returned that error line in File1.py?

Comment: how is the file2 and the file1 are connected. Could you please post full example

Comment: @Arseniy They are 2 separate files. File2.py could be accessed through File1.py like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it a little bit ugly with the [`traceback` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html).

**File1.py**

```
print('this is line 1')
print(5/0)
```

**File2.py**

```
import sys
import traceback
try:
    import test
except Exception as e:
    (exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback) = sys.exc_info()
    trace_back = [traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[-1]][0]
    print("Exception {} is on line {}".format(exc_type, trace_back[1]))
```

**output**

```
this is line 1
Exception <type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'> is on line 2
```

In this case, you will catch all exceptions raised during importing your file, then you will take the last one from the `trace_back`.