# How to call a function from other program

Tags: python, function, call

How to call a function and print from other program?

I've a `textfile.txt` file :

```
"mouse"
"monitor"
"keyboard"
"wire"
```

My script `firstprogram.py` :

```
def call():
  with open('textfile.txt','r') as f:
    input_file = f.readlines()
  for line in input_file:
   print(line)
```

My another script `secondprogram.py` :

```
 from firstprogram import call
 print("hi")
 call()
```

This is my expected output:

```
 hi
 mouse
 monitor
 keyboard
 wire
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script)

Comment: i m new to coding pls explain with my coding...pls help me sir/madam

Comment: you need to learn how to import sir./madam, not much we can do just google it and learn how to do it.
(There is an easy and dirty way with sys.path.append, but stay away from that and learn the __init__.py way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go: First you define the function in firstprogram.py

```
def call():
   print("I am call")
#save as  firstprogram.py
```

in the second program secondprogram.py , just call it like this:

```
from firstprogram import call
call()
```