# How do you run a python file from another python file?

Tags: python

Im trying to run another file from my tkinter login system but i cant find the way to do it

Ive tried import file

```
if (p == '123') and (u == 'test'):
    import correct
```

Im trying to run the file when those are true

Comment: Don't "run the file". Import a function from it at at the beginning of your code, and call that function inside that `if` statement (though what you wrote should technically work if that file contains global code, so I guess you've got some other problem in your code).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script)

Comment: I agree with the first answer, if your point is to use functions / classes / variables... from another file. But still if you REALLY want to run your module you can with  `os.system('py your_module.py')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a file separately without importing it do this.

```py
from os import system
#system calls a command from terminal
system("python <path to python file>")
```

Answer (score 3):

One hacky way to do it, if you really have to is this:

```py
with open("correct.py", "r") as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

But you should avoid doing this if possible. Normally it is better import the file and run a function from it.

Comment: Yes, I accidentally pressed submit before I'd finished – fixed it now!

Comment: Yep! That's what happens when I rush!

Comment: Ikr, so much pressure to get your answer at the top :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use execfile(filepath) to get run