# Getting first and last days of each month, starting with current date

Tags: bash, date, terminal

I want to run a python file multiple times and change input values every time it's run. The input values, in this case, is a website address and two date spans with a given start date and a given end date.

Example:

I want to loop through and run this file with different dates up to 12 months back.

The file

Iteration 1, todays date and the first date of the current month:

```
run -i 'file.py' 'https://www.example.com/' '2019-09-01' '2019-09-12'
```

Iteration 2, the first date of last month and the last date of last month:

```
run -i 'file.py' 'https://www.example.com/' '2019-08-01' '2019-08-31'
```

Iteration 3:

```
run -i 'file.py' 'https://www.example.com/' '2019-07-01' '2019-07-31'
```

...

Keep on iterating 12 months back

I've already managed to build a for loop that generates the dates but i'm having troubles to incorporate the python file.

```
for i in {1..12}; do 
    echo $(date -I -d "2019-09-01 -$i months")
done
```

Output:

```
2019-08-01
2019-07-01
2019-06-01
2019-05-01
2019-04-01
2019-03-01
2019-02-01
2019-01-01
2018-12-01
2018-11-01
2018-10-01
2018-09-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the code below:

```
d1=$(date '+%Y-%m-01')
d2=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
for i in {1..12}; do 
    run -i 'file.py' 'https://www.example.com/' $d1 $d2
    d2=$(date -d "$d1 -1 day"  '+%Y-%m-%d')
    d1=$(date -d "$d2" '+%Y-%m-01')
done
```

Explanation:

- we begin with the first day as `d1` and the current one of the current month as `d2`.
- for each iteration, we deduce `d2` from the previous date `d1`, which is the first day of the previous month, by subtracting one day.

The following command lines will be executed:

```
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-09-01 2019-09-12
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-08-01 2019-08-31
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-07-01 2019-07-31
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-06-01 2019-06-30
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-05-01 2019-05-31
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-04-01 2019-04-30
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-03-01 2019-03-31
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-02-01 2019-02-28
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2019-01-01 2019-01-31
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2018-12-01 2018-12-31
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2018-11-01 2018-11-30
run -i file.py 'https://www.example.com/' 2018-10-01 2018-10-31
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for and well explained.

Comment: @BobHarris, you're welcome! By the way I just realized the output example was wrong, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```sh
run -i 'file.py' 'https://www.example.com/' '2019-09-01' '2019-09-12'
for i in {1..12}; do 
    run -i 'file.py' 'https://www.example.com/' '`echo $(date -I -d "2019-09-01 -$i months")`' '`echo $(date -I -d "2019-09-31 -$i months")`'
done
```

You can use backticks (`) to evaluate a command and substitute in the command's output, like in your case, the dates.

A better way to do this would be to call the [python script from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script) (assuming you are the one who wrote the first script).

Comment: Nice, but won't start with the second argument as being the current date (`2019-09-12`).

Comment: You can have one statement to run for the current month and one loop for rest of the months. Edited my answer.

Comment: Not yet, you hard coded the current date and your backsticks won't be evaluated since they are enclosed by simple quotes. :)