# Make a python script that opens another python script

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am very disappointed that after looking for several hours, I have still not found an answer to: - Make a python script that opens another python script ?

Mabye I don't know how to search for stuff, but I am usually good at finding solutions online.

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.Popen(['C:\Users\user\Documents\run.py'])
```

Here is the python file called "run.py"

```
print('Hello World!')
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you have access to that python script, why don't you just import the content from it?

Comment: Do you want just to open `run.py` as a text file? Or, do you want to execute `run.py`?

Comment: What about this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script)

Comment: I want a script to run several scripts in subfolders automatically so I don't have to do it myself :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `call` library, it's pretty easy:

```
from subprocess import call

call(["python", "your_file.py"])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I will go about it. Suppose you have two files: `Main.py` and `run.py`
and will want `Main.py` to open and run this file `run.py`:

1. this is the content of `Main.py` : it calls `run.py` through import (`run.py` file needs to be in the same folder)

`import run`

2. this is your run.py

`print('Hello World!')`

Then you can run `Main.py` by calling `python Main.py`

the output will be : `Hello World!`

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
your_cmd = "python3 path/to/file/run.py"
p = subprocess.Popen("exec " + your_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i find this to work and it looks clearer:

```
import subprocess
import pathlib


path_to_file=pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
script_path=f'{path_to_file}/your_script.py'

subprocess.run(['python',script_path])
```