# How do I call one Python file from another Python file?

Tags: python, pycharm

So I have multiple Python files, each file being their own console application providing several options to the user. file1.py, file2.py, file3.py etc.

I have another file called menu.py. Within this file I want to offer the user the option to run one of the other python files i.e.

```
option = input("Enter file name to run: ")
if option == "file1": #Code to open file
```

My code would be a lot cleaner than this, but hopefully you understand the point I am trying to get to.

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `os.system()`

You can run a command by

```
command = 'python3 file1.py'
os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is attributed to @balpha and @fantastory.

If you are using Python 2, use

```py
execfile("test2.py")
```

If using Python 3, use

```py
exec(open("test2.py").read())
```

You also might want to see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) on how namespaces are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Josh's answer.

For the cleanest solution, you should use `import` statements to pull code from another file. The way to achieve this would be for each file to have a main function that will serve as an interface. In addition, I also recommend using argparse if the files are command line programs.

If there is only 1 file to be called at a time, the program could look something like:

```py
import argparse

import file1
import file2

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run some files')
parser.add_argument('--file', type=str, dest='file', help='file name', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--options', dest='options', nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.file)

if args.file == 'file1':
    if args.options:
        file1.main(*args.options)
    else:
        file1.main()
elif args.file == 'file2':
    if args.options:
        file2.main(*args.options)
    else:
        file2.main()
```

*file1.py* might look like:

```py
def main(*options):
    print('File 1', options)
```

And you call it like this: `python3 menu.py --file file1 --options option1 option2`