# How to run a python script inside a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script `script1` that have multiple arguments which could be simplified as:

```py
def add_vars(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5):
    sum = var1+var2+var3+var4+var5
    return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter, description="""                                              
    simple addition                                                                                                                              
    """)

    parser.add_argument('var1',  type=float, help='var1')
    parser.add_argument('-var2', type=float, default=20, help='var2')
    parser.add_argument('-var3', type=float, default=30, help='var3')
    parser.add_argument('-var4', type=float, default=40, help='var4')
    parser.add_argument('-var5', type=float, default=50, help='var5')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

    ss = add_vars(args.var1, args.var2, args.var3, args.var4, args.var5)
    print('sum=', ss)
```

in which only `arg1` is required and `arg2`-`arg5` are optional.

I would like to call this script in another Python script with `arg1`, `arg3` just like in the terminal:

```
script1.py 1 -var3 4
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried `os.execl` but without luck.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I'd say using `subprocess` wouldn't be a "better" way but this is a way you could do it?

```py
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["python", "script1.py", "1", "-var3", "4"])

print(out.decode("utf-8"))
```

Output:

```
Namespace(var1=1.0, var2=20, var3=4.0, var4=40, var5=50)
sum= 115.0
<empty line>
```

---

**Original:**

script1.py:

```py
def add_vars(var1, var2=20, var3=30, var4=40, var5=50):
    sum = var1+var2+var3+var4+var5
    return sum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
                                     description="""simple addition""")

    parser.add_argument('var1',  type=float, help='var1')
    parser.add_argument('-var2', type=float, default=20, help='var2')
    parser.add_argument('-var3', type=float, default=30, help='var3')
    parser.add_argument('-var4', type=float, default=40, help='var4')
    parser.add_argument('-var5', type=float, default=50, help='var5')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

    ss = add_vars(args.var1, args.var2, args.var3, args.var4, args.var5)
    print('sum=', ss)
```

script2.py:

```py
import script1

print(script1.add_vars(1, var3=4))
```

`var2=20, var3=30, var4=40, var5=50` sets the default values for the function (just like for `argparse`)

Comment: Excellent. Is there a better way to achieve the same? Using subprocess or so

Answer (score 1):

`if __name__=='__main__'`
resists your program functions to be called in other program
so you can do something like this in in other program

```
from script1.py import add_vars
```

and since you have given arg 1 and 3 default vals in the function you with other arguments so you have to be careful while passing other args , while you are in the other file

```
add_vars(arg1,arg3)
```

if you would have simply call script1.py then this would have not executed

if you have further question do add a comment i'll do make my best to answer your query

if you want to change vals of arg1 and arg3

```
add_vars(arg1=29,arg3=8)
```

you can specify them ,
so that their default value is overrided