# Accessing variable in __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access a variable from a python module which is being run as a script. The variable is defined in the `if __name__ == "__main__"`:

The code I am working with looks something like this:

```
MyCode.py
cmd = 'python OtherCode.py'
os.system(cmd) # Run the other module as a python script

OtherCode.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    var = 'This is the variable I want to access'
```

I was wondering if there was a way to access this variable while still running the OtherCode.py as a script.

Comment: The variable is gone as soon as `os.system(cmd)` returns, as it was only ever define in that process. If you just want the *value* that was assigned to the variable, you'll need to investigate various methods of interprocess communication, ad `OtherCode.py` will have to be modified to cooperate.

Comment: Why not just import the other script? Why does it have to be run via `cmd`? Why do none of these options here work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script

Comment: @RandomDavis: Well, if the variable definition is protected by an import guard as shown, that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`runpy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) module to import the module as `__main__` then extract the variable from the returned dictionary:

```py
import runpy
vars = runpy.run_module("OtherCode", run_name="__main__")
desired_var = vars["var"] # where "var" is the variable name you want
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `os.system`, it runs the specified command as a completely separate process.  You would need to pass the variable through some sort of OS-level communication mechanism: stdout, a socket, shared memory, etc.

But since both scripts are Python, it would be much easier to just `import OtherCode`.  (Though note that you will need to set up `OtherCode.py` inside of a package so that Python knows it can be `import`ed.)

Comment: If *you* `import OtherCode` will `__name__ == "__main__"` be True?

Comment: @wwii No, that is a good point.  `var` would need to be moved into module scope.

Comment: @0x5453 I think you mean "executed unconditionally", because it's *already* at module scope.

Answer (score 0):

While this fix might not be ideal (or what people are looking for if they google it)
I ended up printing out the variable and then used subprocess to get the stdout as a variable:

```
MyCode.py
cmd = 'python OtherCode.py'   
cmdOutput =  subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

OtherCode.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    var = 'This is the variable I want to access'
    print(var)
```

In this case the cmdOutput == var