# How can I send a string from script_1 to script_2?

Tags: python-3.x

Currently I have....

```
file_1.py
x = "Carrots"
print (x)

file_2.py
x = "Spinach"
print (x)

file_3.py
x = "Peas"
print (x)
```

Now let's say I wanted to change `print (x)` to another command. In that case I would need to change `file_1.py`, and `file_2.py`, and `file_3.py`. I would prefer to make changes to one file, which I am calling `main_file.py` to accomplish the same result.

Therefore, I want to create something like...

```
python3 file_1.py | main_file.py
```

where...

```
file_1.py
x = "Carrots"
```

and...

```
main_file.py
print (x)
```

or something like...

```
file_1.py
x = "Carrots"
send x to main_file.py

file_2.py
x = "Spinach"
send x to main_file.py

file_3.py
x = "Peas"
send x to main_file.py
```

where `main_file.py` contains a command such as `print (x)`.

I have reviewed...

1. [Python: Sending a variable to another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066126/python-sending-a-variable-to-another-script)
2. [Python pass a variable to another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296599/python-pass-a-variable-to-another-script)
3. [Pass variable between python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048237/pass-variable-between-python-scripts/16048264)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *main_file.py*:

```py
def action(x):
    print(x)
```

In your *file_1.py* (must be in the same directory as *main.py*):

```py
import main_file

x = "Carrot"
main_file.action(x)
```

---

> Now let's say I had a directory with multiple sub-directories. What would be the best method to have file_1.py, file_2.py, file_3.py and so on (up to, say, several hundred files in perhaps a half a dozen sub-directories) all "find" main_file.py without hard coding a path to main_file.py?

You can order your project structure to something like that:

```
p
├───s1
│   └───file_1.py
├───s2
│   ├───s21
│   │   └───file_3.py
│   └───file_2.py
└───main_file.py
```

Then, in either *file_1.py*, *file_2.py* or *file_3.py*, you can `import main_file` at the top and use as the above snippet. To execute a particular file (let's say, *file_3.py*), you can change your current working directory to `p` using

```
cd p
```

and run

```
python -m s2.s21.file3
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Now let's say I had a directory with multiple sub-directories. What would be the best method to have file_1.py, file_2.py, file_3.py and so on (up to, say, several hundred files in perhaps a half a dozen sub-directories) all "find" main_file.py without hard coding a path to main_file.py?

Comment: @Tiel I've updated my answer, see if this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I appreciate it. I'm going to open another question within the next half hour or so which explains what I am actually trying to do so that you can see "the big picture". Then I will post a link to that question here.

Comment: I just tried to post another question on StackOverflow but received the following error message, "You can only post once every 90 minutes." I intend to post the aforementioned "another question" within the next 24 hours.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention you in my last two comments immediately above.

Comment: Please see the following question I just posted on StackOverflow... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518107/im-trying-to-create-a-simple-text-expander-using-python