# I'm trying to create a simple text expander using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a simple text expander using Python. **Do you have any suggestions for me?**

I'm running Linux (Lubuntu 20.04 LTS). I am only looking for a solution that works on Linux. By the way, as an aside, I presume my solution would work on Macintosh OS as well. As for Windows, I'm not sure.

I've been using [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) on Linux (which is different than, and distinct, from the similarly named Auto**Hot**Key which runs on Windows) for about 6 or 7 years. It works pretty well but it crashes sometimes and is no longer being actively developed.

Essentially I use AutoKey as a text expander. For example, if I type `.tflmk` then AutoKey will replace `.tflmk` with `Thanks for letting me know.`

I wanted a simpler, more reliable solution that AutoKey that would not require me to install an application that might become essentially orphaned.

After some research I found that by adding the following lines...

```
 alias paste-script-1="nohup python3 '~/home/script-1.py' --option& exit"
 alias paste-script-2="nohup python3 '~/home/script-2.py' --option& exit"
 alias paste-script-3="nohup python3 '~/home/script-3.py' --option& exit"
```

to

`.bashrc`

I could run Python scripts from a terminal that would paste into, say, a text document I was working on or a Gmail I was composing, if the Python scripts contained the following information...

```
import pyautogui,pyperclip

x = '''I will get back to you later today.'''
pyperclip.copy(x)
pyperclip.paste()
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')  # ctrl-v pastes.
```

which I could trigger by typing `.iwgbtylt`  into a terminal if the following line were in my `.bashrc` file...

```
 alias .iwgbtylt ="nohup python3 '~/home/IWillGetBack....py' --option& exit"
```

and, of course, if I had created the file `/home/IWillGetBack....py`.

I posted this question [How can I send a string from script_1 to script_2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517297/how-can-i-send-a-string-from-script-1-to-script-2) because it seemed better to me to segregate the each of my text expanders from a "main script" in case I wanted to make changes to the main script.

I expect I will end up with several hundred "text expander snippets" that are located in half a dozen or so sub-directories under a folder such as `~/home/my_text_expanders`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a super simple text expander for my personal use, which I implemented with a Python module 'keyboard' (https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard). I'm working on Windows, but it seems that it can also be used for Linux (and Mac).
At its simplest form, I just run the following code during my work (writing CT reports).

```
import keyboard

abbrev_dict = {
  "ac": "ascending colon", "bl": "benign-looking",
     ...(omitted)... 
  "_vc": "Multifocal atherosclertoic vascular calcification in aorta and its branches."}

for (source, target) in abbrev_dict.items():
    keyboard.add_abbreviation(source, target)

keyboard.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI:

Seems that AutoKey has not been totally `no longer being actively developed` ...
I found it released a new non-beta version these days.

PS: I never used AutoKey ... And just research a little for my potential migration to linux from Windows+AHK

Comment: AutoKey is alive and fairly well, but we really do need one or more additional Python  developers.

We have an active community on our support [forums](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Community).