# How to pass the variable while sourcing .py script inside main python script

Tags: python

I want to pass the "ref" variable while running the old.py in my python script. How can I do it?

```
ref = true
os.system('old.py -setting + ref') ???? (its not correct)
```

what is best way to pass the `ref` variable while running `old.py` inside main python script?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to call a script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `os.system`; use `subprocess` instead.

```
import subprocess


ref = "true"
subprocess.run(["old.py", "-setting", ref])
```

If `ref` really is a Boolean-valued variable, you'll have to convert it to a string first.

```
import subprocess


ref = True
subprocess.run(["old.py", "-setting", str(ref).lower()])
```

Comment: You'll probably want `str(ref).lower()` to maintain the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following code?

```
import os

ref = 'true'
os.system('python old.py -setting ' + ref)
```

It should run the following command in the operating system.

```
python old.py -setting true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting or concatenation.

```
ref = 'true'
os.system(f'old.py -setting {ref}')
```