# How do you make python file run another python file

Tags: python

Here is my code to run another python file

```
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import os
import webbrowser
from subprocess import *

root = Tk()
yes = open('Hello.py')
def Open():
    print(yes)

stup = Button(text='Stop', command=exit)
stup.pack()

g = Button(text='spam',command=Open,bg='red')
g.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

when I run the file it wont show me error but show me this

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Hello.py' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Idk what it mean so can someone correct me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script
Answered here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to call a script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script)

Comment: `open()` is only for opening access to file - and later you can use `read()` to get data from file. And this way you could eventually run text from file using `eval()` but it may need better method.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [runpy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) module:

```py
import runpy

runpy.run_module("module_name")
```