# starting a cronjob with a probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, probability

There is a python script that I want to run as a cronjob with a given probability.

Lets say I want to run that file at after reboot. Thus, using `@reboot /path/to/file`

I don't know whether setting a probability is possible with cronjobs. Currently I'm using another python script to run the desired script. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a probability call to the Python script.

```
import sys
from random import random

run_script_prob = 0.3

if random() > run_script_prob:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm using something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186847/15079222). But I am asking if there is a way to do this directly with cron.