# How to call a python program from inside a python program?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to call a python program from inside a program what do I  use. I have a python file that checks a file name and if it's a certain file I want to run another program. Any suggestions on what to use.

Comment: Your question may have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the os.system command.

```
    import os
    os.system('python my_file.py')
```

i got this from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-make-one-Python-file-run-another

Comment: Well my second program didn't run

Comment: well i got it from the website so idk whats happening i will test

Comment: import os os.system('python my_file.py')   worked for me