# python run multiple scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Hi i would like to run **add1.py** and **add2.py** simultaneously and have searched BAT file and SH file but couldnt do it myself. Anyone can help me? The folder is in the following path `C:\Users\Jia\Downloads\Telegram Bot\Scripts`
I might also add more scripts like **add3.py add4.py** and the list goes on. Does anyone have simple tips that can help me run every script in this folder? Thank you!

It would be even better if the script runs one after another, example **add2.py** runs after **add1.py** finishes.

[image]

Comment: Multiprocessing.....?

Comment: On Windows, google for the "start" command, which will allow you to start something in a batch file without waitling for it top finish. You should start your python.exe with the path to the script file as the first parameter. If you want to run them after each other, do not use "start", but just `<your path>/python.exe <script file>`in your batch file. Running every schript in a folder is a very insecure design. Try to think of something more safe.

Comment: Why not just write Python code that `imports` the appropriate top-level functions and calls them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone else already suggested, you could make a python file which executes your N python scripts.

Using `subprocess` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11230471/11962413

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("./test1.py", shell=True)
subprocess.call("./test2.py", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run: `python add1.py & python add2.py`. If you only want the second one to run if the first executes successfully, use `python add1.py && python add2.py`.

Running them at the same time would use something called concurrency, which would require some modifications to your script.

NOTE: This will only work on Windows. On Linux or MacOS, you would use: `python add1.py ; python add2.py`

You can manually add more scripts. To runn every python file in a folder, you could use: `python *.py` if you imported them all as modules into a new file called `main.py` and executed them in what ever order you like in that file.

Comment: can you check the first line? Both commands look the same to me.

Comment: Sorry, meant to put a double & for conditional execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, if you are just tying to run python file:

```
import os

lst=[l for l in os.listdir() if l.endswith(".py")]
for ls in lst:
   os.system(f'python {ls}')
```

Or if the name has some pattern or it is sure then, try this:

```
import os
for i in range(1,<up to last name+1>):
    os.system(f"python add{i}.py")
```