# How to convert output from subprocess to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to take the output of a Python script and convert it into list of dictionaries to perform some action. I have written a below code:

```
import subprocess
import json
chief_complaint = """ "Eernise, Randell is an 64-year-old male" """
command= """python predict_icd.py --cc """+str(chief_complaint)
command_proc=subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print("response - ",command_proc.stdout.read())
```

The output that I am getting of above code is:

```
command_proc.stdout.read() -  b"[{'text': 'CHA', 'start': 51, 'end': 54, 'code': ''}, {'text': 'CHA', 'start': 221, 'end': 224, 'code': ''}, {'text': 'dog', 'start': 286, 'end': 289, 'code': ''}, {'text': 'Schizophrenia', 'start': 351, 'end': 364, 'code': 'F20'}, {'text': 'chronic pain', 'start': 366, 'end': 378, 'code': 'G89.29'}, {'text': 'chest pain', 'start': 599, 'end': 609, 'code': 'R07.89'}, {'text': 'palpitations', 'start': 613, 'end': 625, 'code': 'R00.2'}, {'text': 'cough', 'start': 829, 'end': 834, 'code': 'R05'}, {'text': 'wheezing', 'start': 836, 'end': 844, 'code': 'R06.2'}, {'text': 'pain', 'start': 966, 'end': 970, 'code': ''}, {'text': 'schizophrenia', 'start': 1078, 'end': 1091, 'code': 'F20'}]\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolutely best solution is to not run Python as a subprocess of itself. Instead, refactor `predict_icd.py` so you can `import` it and call its functions directly. See [What is the best way to call a script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script)

Your second best option is to change `predict_icd.py` so that it prints its results in a standard format like JSON. Then you can call it from any tool, not just Python.

The distant third option is to go with what you have and use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse out the results.  I have also refactored to [avoid the pesky and unnecessary `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) and fix the orphaned `Popen`.

```py
import subprocess
# import json  # unused import
from ast import literal_eval

chief_complaint = """ "Eernise, Randell is an 64-year-old male" """
command_proc = subprocess.run(
    ['python', 'predict_icd.py', '--cc', chief_complaint],
    capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
response = literal_eval(command_proc.stdout)
print("response = ", response)
```

In some more detail, `Popen` will only *start* a process; you have to take care of it during its lifetime if you do that - but `subprocess.run()` already takes care of all this plumbing for you. Like its documentation says, avoid `Popen` when the higher-level functions from the standard library already do what you want.

Notice also the `text=True` which tells Python to send and receive text, not `bytes` to and from the subprocess.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using python3.6 and using your code, I got 2 errors 1st  - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'....2nd - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Comment: The keyword arguments `capture_output` and `text` are a bit newer than that. If you are really stuck on 3.6, you'll have to revert to using explicit `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` etc and switch to the legacy synonym `universal_newlines=True` instead of `text=True` ... still `run` should be a significant improvement over an incomplete ad-hoc reimplementation over `Popen`.  You'll notice that 3.6 is slated to go EOL at the end of 2021.

Comment: And of course, my primary recommendation remains to not run Python as a subprocess of itself.