# Running a file via import from a function

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to run another .py file via the following script. However, it will not run the other file.

```
import time
 
def talking():
   import talk

list1 = ["Whats the time", "WHATS THE TIME?", "WHATS THE TIME" "whats the time", "whats the time?", "Whats the time?"]
input("Whats your name?: ")
while True:

 ask = input("How can i help?: ")

 if ask in list1:
     talking()
 time.sleep(1)

 if ask == "hi":
     print("Hi?")
     time.sleep(1)
```

The file called talk currently simply contains the following:

```
import time

time.sleep(4)
print("Hello World")
time.sleep(20)
```

I have done this before but since then i have completely forgotten.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including input, expected output, actual output, and minimal code, like to start, `time.sleep()` doesn't seem relevant to the problem, and the input from `input("Whats your name?: ")` is unused.

Comment: With all the fluff removed, I'm not able to reproduce the issue. `tmp.py` = `import talk` and `talk.py` = `print("Hello World")` -> running `tmp.py` prints `Hello World`.

Answer (score 3):

As written in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script) you can execute a python  *executed.py* script from another python *executor.py* script using `exec(open("executed.py").read())` in *executor.py*.

In your case your `talking()` function becomes:

```
def talking():
    exec(open("talk.py").read())
```

This **isn't the best way** anyway. If you want to use your `talk.py` file as a **library**, you should define functions inside `talk.py` file, then importing them in the file where you want to execute them. Code below is an example.

`talk.py`

```
def talking():
    print("I'm talking")
```

`caller_script.py`

```
import talk

talk.talking()  # this will print "I'm talking"
```

Answer (score -1):

From your question which is interesting (even if written in an unclear way in some places, but it is understood), I read import talk in the main py file function, so I assume you want to import the secondary external file and use as a library.

To call an external file in the function of a main file, you have to call the name of the file and then of the function that you will have to create to be called. So it will be something like this:

In the main file `main.py`, you have to write like this:

```
#from file_name import function_name
from talk import example

def talking():
      talk_function = talk.example()
    return talk_function
```

If you want to import it from inside a folder, you have to write `from Folder_name.talk import example`

In the secondary file `talk.py` (the one you want to recall) you have to write:

```
def example():
    time.sleep(4)
    print("Hello World")
    time.sleep(20)
```

You can also run the whole file directly as @Marte Valerio Falcone said in his nice answer

Comment: Please check your indentation, and make sure you're not referencing an undefined variable (`result`).

Comment: @CrazyChucky Ok, now i control, then I edit the answer. Excuse