# Unable to run one python script from another python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to run one script from another script. I've read; [What is the best way to call a script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script) and I can't seem to get this to work.

My main script (Script A) does a lot of image processing and GUI interactions. However, randomly an error message or other window might appear interrupting the GUI interactions until the message or window is closed.

I've written a second script (Script B) that I want to run perpetually that closes these windows or error messages when discovered.

I'm trying to call Script B from Script A like this:

```
import close_windows

close_windows.closeWindows
print("Starting Close Windows....")
```

And Script B is:

```
import pyautogui as py

def closeWindows():

    image = r'C:\image.jpg'
    image2 = r'C:\image2.jpg'

    while True:
        foundimage = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image) 
        foundimage2 = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image2) 
    
        if foundimage or foundimage2 != None:
            py.click(1887, 65)
```

When I run script B independently it works, when I try running it via Script A with `close_windows.closeWindows` nothing happens.

I've also tried `from close_windows import closeWindows` and calling `closeWindows` but again, nothing happens.

Comment: you should **call** the function `close_windows.closeWindows`; i.e. `close_windows.closeWindows()`.

Comment: `close_windows.closeWindows` should be `close_windows.closeWindows()`

Comment: Everything below close_windows.closeWindows turns grey when I add the (). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Probably because the while loop in closeWindows() does not stop.

Comment: That makes sense, I assume then this approach isn't going to work at all!

Comment: @mak47 not unless you have some way to break the while loop or not use it at all.

Comment: As a side note - `if foundimage or foundimage2 != None:` clearly shows there is misunderstanding how to test multiple variables against single value. Nevertheless it will not work - [as mentioned in the docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) _As of version 0.9.41, if the locate functions can’t find the provided image, they’ll raise `ImageNotFoundException` instead of returning `None`._. Finally, the `"Starting Close Windows...."` will be printed on screen nly after the function has actually finished.

Comment: While that might not be the correct way to use it, it definitely works

Comment: Sorry, but I trust the docs, unless you use pre-0.9.41 version. What happens if neither of images is located?

Comment: @mak47 What is the use of the while loop? Cant you just remove it and check what you need to check and then py.click if they are not None?

Comment: If none of the images are located nothing happens. I'm happy to share the full script if you like, I use this all over the place and have been using it for about two years without issue. @buran

Comment: @user56700 the main script runs 24/7 and the errors appear randomly, I can put the check-in against every single GUI interaction I suppose but I thought it would more sense just to have a script running a also 24/7 to deal with any random windows that open. It's probably case for multiprocessing  I guess

Comment: @mak47 I see, then I would run it in a separate thread using multiprocessing.

Comment: I've been trying to avoid multiprocessing but it is probably time! Thank you