# How to execute python file inside another with specific parameters?

Tags: python, terminal, parameters

In terminal I would type something close to:

```
python main.py --something-something parameter1 --something- parameter2
```

Because that's how the program works. I need to run main.py in another python script but also need to have "--something-something parameter1 --something- parameter2" as part of it.

I have already looked [What is the best way to call a script from another script? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script) and some others but they did not answer to my problem.

Is this possible with importing os?
Lets say the parameter 2 is ID and its value is integer 1234 and parameter 1 dog is "dachshund".

I tried something close to:

```
dog = "dachshund"
ID = 1234
os.system("python main.py --something-something {dog} --something- {ID}")
```

But obviously it did not work and there must the right way to do this and there may even be better ways than using os.system(). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create the string you will use first

```
pythonCall = 'python main.py --something-something {} --something- {}'.format(dog, ID)
os.system(pythonCall)
```