# Running scripts from a text file

Tags: python

I'm new and I'm trying to run a script that runs a sequence of scripts based on what I put in a text file.

For example, I have `Script1.py` with `print("Script1")` ... then `Script2.py` with `print("Script2")`, `Script3.py` with `print("Script3")` ... and in the text file to once:

```
Script1.py
Script3.py
```

then another time to have:

```
Script2.py
Script1.py
Script3.py
Script2.py
```

And the main script to execute the sequence of scripts in the text file.

PS: Apologies for my English language

Thank you in advance

```py
def Script1():
    Script1.py
def Script2():
    Script2.py
def Script3():
    Script3.py

commands_table = {'Script1':Script1, 'Script2':Script2, 'Script3':Script3}

with open('test.txt', 'r') as command_file:
     for cmd in command_file:
         cmd = cmd.strip()
         commands_table[cmd]()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to call a script from another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script)

Comment: "I'm trying to run a script that runs a sequence of scripts based on what I put in a text file."  So the file specifies the name of a python file or the name of a python function?

Comment: Yes. The file specifies the name of a python files to run

Comment: This is a strange way to do things. Why not just pass the names of the features that you want run on the command line (e.g. main.py Script1 Script2) and then the main script imports and executes the relevant Python source?

Answer (score 0):

Use `import` to grab functions from other files

### scripts.py

```
def script1():
  print('1')

def script2():
  print('2')
```

### app.py

```
import scripts

commands_table = {'Script1':scripts.script1, 'Script2':scripts.script2}

with open('test.txt') as command_file:
     for cmd in command_file:
         commands_table[cmd.strip()]()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

with open('test.txt', 'r') as command_file:
    commands = command_file.read()
    commandsList = commands.splitlines()
    for cmd in commandsList:
        os.system(cmd)
```

You have to chmod +x all your scripts to be executable and the first line of each script should be:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3
```

or whatever your python interpreter is