# how to modularize django settings.py?

Tags: python, django

When you install a new django application, you have to add/modify your settings.py module.

For a project I'm trying to make that module a python subpackage and create a module for each application:

```
settings\
    __init__.py
    base.py
    admin.py
    feincms.py
    ...
```

The problem I'm confronted with is how to merge settings.py attributes (INSTALLED_APPS for example is a tuple of values) that are getting values in the different submodules?

Thanks

---

Ok, I asked the wrong question (got the right answer for it though). My question should have been, how to get attributes from all submodules and merge them? Django will import settings and expects everything to be there.

Comment: I created https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#SettingInheritancewithHierarchy as my preferred solution. Allows for inheritance from a common file in any deployment environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be interested in [this solution](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#UsingalistofconffilesTransifex); uses execfile() to load a series of settings files in order, where each file has full access to settings from previously-loaded files, to update, modify, etc.

```py
$ ls settings/

10-base.conf
20-engines.conf
30-site.conf
...

$ cat settings.py

import os.path
import glob
conffiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'settings', '*.conf'))
conffiles.sort()
for f in conffiles:
    execfile(os.path.abspath(f))
```

Comment: yes, i ended up writing a solution similar to that. but execfile() is now discouraged. so i used exec() and compile()

Comment: victor, it would be interesting to see the code for your solution

Comment: so sorry guys. that was like 3 years ago and i don't remember the app i was working on. but this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/437857/125560. also be sure to be up to date with these things. i am seeing that there are a few other alternatives for Python3

Answer (score 8):

"When you install a new django application, you have to add/modify your settings.py module."

I think this is fine as is.

I don't see any reason to change or modify this at all.

What we do, however, is to "subclass" the core settings module.

Our developer-specific and installation-specific files have names like `settings_devxy_linux2` and `settings_checkout_win32`, etc.

Each of these files starts with `from settings import *` to import the core settings and extend those core settings with overrides for a specific installation and platform.

It doesn't require any real work.  It does, however, mean that we do most things with `django-admin.py` because our settings aren't called `settings`.

Comment: So, are these the files you specify in `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in the environment? We went sort of the opposite direction: we have `settings.py` but it does a try/include of local_early_setting.py and of local_late_settings.py. These files differ from development to staging. The basic `settings.py` contains the correct production values.

Comment: We specify `settings_prod_linux2` for production; it imports the core `settings` that define the project as a whole.  I use `settings_devsl_win32` for development; it imports the core `settings`.  Since it's simple overrides, there's no "logic".  No "if", no "try".

Comment: Good point. We had to explicitly exclude our local*settings files from Mercurial so they didn't accidentally end up in production. Thanx for the idea.

Comment: Peter's plan suffers from the problem of the original question: imported modules can't easily e.g. add items to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 6):

I've used this work-around:

**settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('whatever',)
import more_settings
more_settings.modify(globals())
```

**more_settings.py**:

```
def modify(settings):
    settings['INSTALLED_APPS'] += ('another_app',)
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to handle single-inheritance. Next step would be YAML.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same structure of settings files and I do the following to import the settings of the submodules:

```
def load_settings_file(file):
    file = open(os.path.join(INSTALL_DIR, '<projectname>', 'settings', file + '.py'))
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    return content

for submodule in ['base', 'admin', 'feincms']:
    exec(load_settings_file(submodule))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer more magic than in my previous `more_settings.modify()` approach, try this:

**settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('whatever',)
import more_settings
more_settings.modify(globals())
```

**more_settings.py**:

```
def config(INSTALLED_APPS=(), **other_settings):
    INSTALLED_APPS += ('another_app',)
    del other_settings
    return locals()

def modify(settings):
    settings.update(config(**settings))
```

Pros: no need to refer to settings with dict notation

Cons: must define modified settings as kwargs for `config()`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the best way to "merge" varies, attributes by attributes.  For example, given several tuples (from the `INSTALLED_APPS` of various submodules), you might simply concatenate them into a new tuple (for the `INSTALLED_APPS` attribute of the package as a whole), or, if possible duplications are a problem, so something smarter to remove the duplications (in this case you may not care about ordering, so simply `tuple(set(tup1+tup2+tup3))` might suffice).

For other cases ("merging" dictionaries, "merging" settings which are just scalars or strings, etc) you'll need different strategies (maybe successive `.update` calls for the dictionaries, pick just one according to some criteria for the scalars or strings, etc, etc) -- I just don't see a "one size fits all" approach working here.

Answer (score -1):

just put

```
from base import *
from admin import *
...
```

in ur **init**.py
that should work

i used it for different sites

```
base/settings.py # common settings: db, apps, ...
base/sites/website1/settings.py # site_id, custom middleware 
base/sites/website2/settings.py # site_id, custom middleware
```

the website settings import the common settings with

```
from base.settings import *
```

and define custom attribtues