# My settings.py file in Django is getting too long. How do I split it into two?

Tags: python, django

How do I do that?  split up 2 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although my solution is not as complex as the ones above, they fit my simple needs: I have some imports in my settings.py file:

```
try:
    from settings_local import *
except ImportError:
    pass

try:
    from settings_production import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

And then I have a **settings_local.py** file in my local development folder (which I don't upload to the server) and where I overwrite local settings. Then I have a **settings_production.py** server where I keep settings needed for the production environment.

You can use this technique to import other settings files as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in any file you like and import it somewhere in your main settings file.

So you could set up new settings `my_new_settings.py` anywhere django can reach, and import it at the end of your real `settings.py`.

```
# settings.py
# ...
from my_new_settings import *
```

Answer (score 2):

These pages might help: [discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035733/how-to-modularize-django-settings-py), discussion on [djangoproject.com](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a pythonista, so my take might just be the most un-pythonic way to do this. Having said that, this is how I split the settings for our Django app:

Instead of a single `settings.py` file, we have `settings/__init__py`. It contains imports for all the settings sections, which are placed in the settings directory.

```
# settings/__init__.py
from .foo import *
from .bar import *

# settings/foo.py
FOO="test"

# settings/bar.py
BAR="quz"
```

From the perspective of the application, this is still the same old settings module; from yours, it's a clean structure of configuration data.

Comment: I actually think this is the most pythontic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create `new_settings.py` file to contain part of `settings.py`, and import that file wherever you need it.