# What is the correct way to use different const data in local dev and production?

Tags: django, facebook, deployment

There are many things that are different in deployment and production. For example, in case of using Facebook API, I need to change id of application(because there are different id for testing and production) every time I push update to the app.

I update only app, so what do usually django developers do in this case? Possibly saving a variable to settings.py and then getting it from there or creating separated file in virtual environment folder, which in my case at least is also separated ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to modularize django settings.py?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035733/how-to-modularize-django-settings-py)

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way of splitting your Django settings for prod and dev -- developers are encouraged to find a way that works for them. The Django docs list out several good options here: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings