# Python: Execute multiple Scripts simultaneously from same Interpreter

Tags: python

I have a **python script**, which is executing again **4-5 python scripts**.
For performance reasons i want to use same interpreter for executing all the script.

How could I handle this issue?

Answer (score 8):

The obvious solution (which may require a little tweaking) is to just call the main function of each script from a master script.  E.g., if script1.py contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def main():
  // Do something
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

put in master.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import script1
def main():
  script1.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

You can continue this pattern for as many scripts as you want.

Comment: to make it "simultanseos", `multithreading`, `multiprocessing` modules could be used

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for the [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) function in Python 2.x.

In Python 3 it was removed, but [there are simple alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a package to execute multiple scripts from the same interpreter (sequentially not simultaneously).

**Installation**:

```
pip install mand
```

---

**Usage**:

```
mand script1.py script2.py script3.py script4.py
```

You can specify module paths or module names.

---

You may be able to run scripts at the 'same time' on using the 
 [runpy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) stdlib module (for python3) and [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) stdlib module. Where you call `runpy.run_path` or `runpy.run_module` in separate threads, but you will only see performance benefits if the modules are IO bound and not CPU bound.

---

Using multiprocessing or os.system will spawn separate interpreters for each script, so the modules wouldn't be running in the same interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The currently executing interpreter is available in `sys.executable`. You can just pass that explicitly to subprocess.Popen as the first argument, or pass it as the 'executable' argument.

Comment: sys.executable is just a string containing the path of the python program.  When he says "use same interpreter", I assume he means the same process, not just the same on-disk executable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is recommended, but worst case scenario you could make the system 'run' each script from within another:

```
import os
os.system('python script1.py')
os.system('python script2.py')
os.system('python script3.py')
os.system('python script4.py')
```