# Can the FPU rounding mode set from a Python process be altered by another Python process?

Tags: python, multithreading, process, fpu, gil

I use much the libqd library which requires setting the FPU rounding mode before any computation. Until now I was mainly using it in C programs but I would like to use it from Python scripts from time to time.

I heard about the *global interpreter lock* (GIL) which is described at https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock or in the answer to this question [same python interpreter instance running multiple scripts simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690327/same-python-interpreter-instance-running-multiple-scripts-simultaneously)

In the first of these two pages, I can read: "The GIL is controversial because it prevents multithreaded CPython programs from taking full advantage of multiprocessor systems in certain situations."

Thus I wonder whether a very long computation (several days for instance) could be disturbed by another Python program running on the same machine: could it happen that the FPU rounding mode would be changed by another process during the computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the GIL is per-process. You're running a seperate interpreter per each process. The operating system should make sure different processes can't affect each other.

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690327/same-python-interpreter-instance-running-multiple-scripts-simultaneously) suggests that the operating system may share some memory between these different processes, but only memory that's the same in both.