# How does IPython's magic %paste work?

Tags: python, ipython

I want to copy already indented Python code / whole functions and classes into IPython. Everytime I try the indentation is screwed up and I get following error message:

`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<ipython-input-23-354f8c8be51b>, line 12)`

`If you want to paste code into IPython, try the %paste and %cpaste magic functions.`

Comment: I know, it is probably already on stackoverflow, but it did not find it after 3 searches, so I added my own version.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can't copy to IPython directly. This are the steps:

1. Copy the lines you want to copy into IPython into the clipboard
2. Enter `%paste` into IPython
3. Press enter
4. Profit!

Comment: %paste requires Tkinter though, so if you don't have that another good bet is %cpaste

Comment: You actually can copy code to IPython directly: you may have to first disable auto-indentation by entering `%autoindent`.

Comment: In **`Ipython 5`**  you can just paste the code. Don't need `%paste` anymore. Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38419584/2248627).

Comment: You don't need the % before `paste` either.

Comment: i know that is a really old thread but `%autoindent` did the trick

Answer (score 49):

A clarification on the steps:

- First, copy target lines into your clipboard.
- Type into the iPython prompt:

  - If on Tkinter: enter `%paste`
  - Otherwise: enter `%cpaste`
- Paste (Ctrl-V) and hit enter.
- Then type `--` and hit enter.

For example:

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:for l in "Hello World":
:    print l,
:--
H e l l o   W o r l d
```

Comment: You do not have to Ctrl-V. Only type %paste and press enter.

Answer (score 25):

As of **Ipython 5** you don't need any magic command, just paste it

[image: ipython5]

> Thanks to `prompt_toolkit`, `IPython` now supports:
>
> - Syntax highlighting as you type
> - Real multi-line editing (up and down arrow keys move between lines)
> - Multi-line paste without breaking indentation or immediately executing code
> - Better code completion interface (we plan to improve that more) Optional mouse support

More on this [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/release-of-ipython-5-0-8ce60b8d2e8e)

To upgrade `ipython` to the latest version

```
pip install ipython --upgrade
```

Comment: Is it possible to paste multi-lines and execute the code automatically at each line?

Comment: yes, just paste the code and press enter. if you want to debug check out %pdb or ipdb.  [example](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9642)

Comment: This also supports output of the Python repl, code that starts with three `>` signs like this: `>>> a = 1 + 2`

Comment: All this time i been doing %cpaste.. nice!

Comment: I *think* it depends on the *environment* from which you are doing the pasting and *how* you are doing the pasting? My colleague is using Windows 10's command prompt to SSH into our Linux host, opens ipython in a Docker container there and tries to paste already-indented code (by *right-clicking*), and he gets extra indentation even in iPython 7.8.0. The way I understand command prompt's right-click behavior is that it actually just takes whatever is in the clipboard and outputs it character by character as though you are typing it. So iPython has no way to know you are in fact pasting.

Answer (score 7):

`%paste`  requires `Tkinter`. If you  are in  ubuntu, you can  install it by

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

If you are on Python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Then  restart ipython and use `%paste` to paste  from your  clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

One of the useful answers was lost in the comments, so wanted to restate it along with adding a reference for another useful IPython magic function.

First to restate what @EOL said, one way to solve OP's problem is to turn off auto-indentation by first running `%autoindent` and doing the paste (not needed if you are using `%paste`, of course).

Now to add more information to what is already there here, one more useful mode in IPython is `%doctest_mode` which allows you to copy paste example and test snippets from doc strings. This is also useful to execute interactive python session output that you could find in documentation and online forums, without having to first strip out the prompt strings.

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu users who are on Python 3.

The `python-tk` is for Python 2.

To make `%paste` work on Python 3, install the `python3-tk` package:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```