# IPython: Editing %cpaste input

Tags: python, shell, ipython

I'm trying to edit a `%cpaste`-ed function - but I can't find keyboard shortcuts for moving up or down a line.

p.s. I know I can use %edit,  %run - but that's inconvenient for a number of reasons if the changes that need to be made are small (among other things pasting into `%edit` won't automatically strip `>>>` and `...`)

Further `%ed` is incapable of reading pasted text from a block i.e. `%paste foo` `%edit foo` does not work.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is 'you can't'. Sorry.

The slightly longer answer is that "Cpaste will read in and execute **pre-formatted** blocks of text.  There's no scope to edit once you're in there - it's not vim or nano you're working in.

From the iPython documentation:

> Paste & execute a pre-formatted code block from clipboard.
>
> You must terminate the block with ‘–’ (two minus-signs) or Ctrl-D
>   alone on the line. You can also provide your own sentinel with ‘%paste
>   -s %%’ (‘%%’ is the new sentinel for this operation).
>
> The block is dedented prior to execution to enable execution of method
>   definitions. ‘>’ and ‘+’ characters at the beginning of a line are
>   ignored, to allow pasting directly from e-mails, diff files and
>   doctests (the ‘...’ continuation prompt is also stripped). The
>   executed block is also assigned to variable named ‘pasted_block’ for
>   later editing with ‘%edit pasted_block’.
>
> You can also pass a variable name as an argument, e.g. ‘%cpaste foo’.
>   This assigns the pasted block to variable ‘foo’ as string, without
>   dedenting or executing it (preceding >>> and + is still stripped)
>
> ‘%cpaste -r’ re-executes the block previously entered by cpaste.
>   ‘%cpaste -q’ suppresses any additional output messages.

Realistically, my workflow is largely as described in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25129812/1293222).  I edit the code in textwrangler or PyCharm, and use %cpaste to run it in terminal for early debugging.  It's an extra step, but right now it seems unavoidable.  You may potentially be able to wrap the %capste in the edit-syntax_error() terminal magics, but I haven't tried it.

The [terminal magics](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/api/generated/IPython.Magic.html) are listed in full there.

Comment: But it seems very strange that something like %paste foo, %edit foo, isn't part of a the built in work flow. P.S. I know I looked through all the terminal magics and was rather amazed that line editing isn't supported - and figured I was missing something obvious perhaps (for example in the default Julia interactive console I can up-arrow and than up/down arrow any lines of the previously entered block). P.P.S. Do you have any idea why people are down-voting this *confused*

Comment: I don't disagree - I find it a bit of a faff, but unfortunately for your answer, it's the correct response.  Maybe you could fix it and do a pull request for it?  I'd use it...

Comment: TBH, I was thinking of forking something simpler - honestly, I find the IPython interface more distracting than helpful (maybe I'm just used to the default interactive shell, among my other complaints is that they don't give %config access to colors and it requires manually editing the .py files) - the only features I really want is to configure my tab length, and line-editing.

Comment: If you just do `%edit`, it will create an empty temporary file and open it in a text editor. You can paste code in there and edit it. When you save and exit, IPython will execute the code.

Answer (score 1):

While editing a `%cpaste` won't work, you *can* edit a module and `reload` it.

```
In [1]: import mymodule

In [2]: mymodule.function()
Out[2]: 'result'
```

< editing the module in an editor... >

```
In [3]: reload(mymodule)
Out[3]: <module 'mymodule' from 'mymodule.py'>

In [4]: mymodule.function()
Out[4]: 'new result'
```

The downside is that you cannot use `from mymodule import`, because `reload` only takes a module as an argument.