# Else not working in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

[image]I'm new in Python. I'm trying to use an else statement in IPython but I get an error message:
"Identation error: unindent does not match any outer identation level." I have looked for similar questions with Python, but the issues were linked to a mix use of tabulation key and spaces to increment or to supplementary spaces/characters. Here, I'm using 4 spaces in front of each print statement without any supplementary (hidden) character (except of course one carriage return by line). The 'if' part alone works but not with the 'else' part.

```
x = True
if x == True:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('nok')
```

Update: Here is a screenshot showing Ipython version, code and erreor message.

Comment: @EricRenouf: I don't think that that's the point. The syntax error is the issue here.

Comment: This is extremely hard for us to debug here, because we can't see exactly what you entered into the IPython session.

Comment: Do you actually *unindent* (backspace four times) to enter the `else:` line?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but it is always better if you indent using a single space so that the 4 space confusion is averted. Specially for a simple code block like this.

Comment: @dunder: 'always better'? I strongly disagree. Besides, IPython *autoindents* for you.

Comment: The code OP provided works on itself. Without more info this problem is not reproducable, therefore it should be closed until OP edits his post.

Comment: I have successfully copy/pasted/ran this code.  You'll have to double check your indents, because maybe stackoverflow's autoformatting removed whitespace for you

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Not sure to good understand. I wrote this example in notebook and I pasted it into IPython.

Comment: @ChristianColot: I've written a speculative answer below. Note that I copied and pasted the full error message into my answer. If you were to do the same in your question we'd already have a lot more information. Including the actual text you copied and pasted (in addition to the error) would be better still.

Comment: @ChristianColot: right, you copied and pasted; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython auto-indents blocks for compound statements, so to enter the `else:` line you have to manually *unindent* again.

I can only reproduce your error if I do not un-indent properly; hitting backspace between 1 and 3 times, instead of 4.

Note the extra space before `else:` in this error example, where I used backspace 3 times:

```
In [2]: if x == True:
   ...:     print('ok')
   ...:  else:
  File "<ipython-input-2-915b4c0eb5ea>", line 3
    else:
         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

IPython allows you to edit your block; just use the Up arrow key to recall the failed piece of text, and remove the extraneous spaces at the start of the `else:` line.

If you are not typing in code by hand, don't copy-and-paste code directly. Use the `%paste` command instead, and IPython will paste the code *for you*, avoiding any auto-indent issues:

```
In [3]: %paste
x = True
if x == True:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('nok')
## -- End pasted text --
ok
```

See `%paste?` for more information.

Comment: In between,  I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886946/how-does-ipythons-magic-paste-work which watches your proposition %paste. It works.